# Python Speech recognition produces bad results

Tags: python, windows-10, speech-recognition, python-3.6

I'm trying to get my speech recognition script working but it can't understand me.

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

def initSpeech():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=2)
        print("Set minimum energy threshold to {}".format(r.energy_threshold))
        print("Say something")

        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=10)

        command = ""
        try:
            command = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except:
            print("Coundn't understand you!")

        print(command)

initSpeech()
```

This is my code to recognize my voice but it always prints out `"Coundn't understand you!"` when I record my voice using python with the following script and put the wave file as input for the speech recognition it works fine:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

This script to record my voice and then using this file "output.wav" as input for the speech recognition.

EDIT:

With,

```
with open("microphone-results.wav", "wb") as f:
        f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
```

I recorded my voice which will be analyzed. And it sounded really bad, low and slow like in bad movies with an voice changer. 
Maybe this is a hint for the solution. I already checked the settings of chuck_size and sample_rate these are identical with the settings in my recording script above.
My system: Windows 10

There is also an issue on github [github issue 358](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/358)

Python: 3.6

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "not working" is not a proper description.

Comment: Start by not catching *every possible exception*. Do not use a blanket `except`; remove the `try..except` and tell us what exception is thrown. Include the full traceback.

Comment: I already did. I her an Unknown Value exception from the google recognition. This is probably caused by the bad audio quality (see github issue)

Comment: The most likely cause of your recorded audio sounding "like a voice changer" is a sample rate mismatch. Even more likely is that the specified sample rate for the .WAV file is lower than that of your audio interface upon recording, resulting in a severe downward pitch-shift upon saving, as proper sample rate conversion isn't performed. So my suggestion: explicitly specify the sampling frequency of `sr.Microphone()` and ensure that it's the same as the source (audio interface/microphone) that you're actually using.

Comment: try listening to your recorded audio by saving it in wav format. Secondly, don't use "try" method and see what are the exact errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your audio is obviously not recorded properly, and this leads to recognition failure. My guess is that `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise` is failing you (automatic speech/silence detectors are not simple to implement). Start with removing this line and manually set

```
r.energy_threshold = 50
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = False
```

After that, save the recorded audio into .WAV file and listen. You have to get your audio clear before you send it to ASR engine.

Also, I recommend you to make sure that you are using the microphone you intended to use

```
print(Microphone.list_microphone_names()[0])
```

Comment: I am using `recognize_sphinx` and tested `recongize_google` too. and i still can't get it to transcribe my speech properly. what setting do i tweak. here's the recorded audio converted to wav file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QTf-_g4M6mv7hVye2BoLN-tBARJs3LPb

Comment: The audio you provided is quite noisy and the speaker has an accent.The existing technologies provide low quality of transcription in such conditions.